# How can I profile a full R flexdashboard app to see what might be taking the most time/memory?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

Does anyone know how to profile a full flexdashboard app?

The [profvis library](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/05/23/profiling-with-rstudio-and-profvis/) looks promising but it appears to only support shiny apps.

What is the best way to profile a flexdashboard app based on Rmarkdown?

Thanks!
Melissa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
profvis::profvis(rmarkdown::run("flexdashboard.Rmd"))
```

to start a flexdashboard app named `flexdashboard.Rmd` in the current working directory and profile its runtime behavior.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for syntax to kick it off for an Rmarkdown. Initially this gave me a pandoc.exe out of memory error but once I added a prof_output to write the output to it seemed to work fine. Marking as the answer!